# Mocking a TypeORM transaction with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, mocking, typeorm

I have a NodeJS app using Typescript, TypeORM as ORM and Jest as the testing framework.

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that creates a few models instances, then tries to save them within a single transaction, as follows:

```
  await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(firstModel);
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(secondModel);
  });
```

How can I mock `getManager()`, `EntityManager` and `.transaction()`, with jest, so that the underlying ConnectionManager is not actually accessed? Ideally I would want the called to `getManager` and `transaction` to be routed to mock implementations.

Comment: This issue can be helpful
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5308

Comment: If you mock `getManager` then `transaction` and `transactionEntityManager` are whatever you define in that mock. Have you tried something, can you give a [mre] to illustrate the current problem?

Comment: I tried to mock getManager() but couldn't figure out how to mock specific functions imported from an external module (official Jest docs and most examples online demonstrate how to mock whole modules).

The relevant examples I could find online behaved differently when I implemented them.

Will try to give minimal reproducible example.